# Problem when comparing two numeric values in SAS

Tags: sas, comparison

Long story short, I need to compare two data sets (`A` and `B`). `B` should be a copy of `A` but on an Impala server. Everyday I am retrieving `B` to SAS from the Impala server through a SQL pass-through.

I am writing a program that will be run everyday to make sure those two data sets match 1:1.
However, I am struggling with numerical approximations (precision).

Here is an example of A:

| ID | value |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 0 |
| 02 | 5000 |
| 03 | 978908.69 |
| 04 | 109789503.12 |
| 05 | 49505954.92 |

In order to make the comparison, I am concatenating the two columns in a `conc` column and then I am comparing `A` and `B`.

```
data want;
set have;
conc=cats(id,value);
run;
```

This basically works for all the observations except one.
The observation has a value for `A` of `9128554507.9` and `B` of `9128554507.8`. No format or informat are applied to the variables.

[image]

However, when applying a `comma32.30` format on the value variable, I see that for `A` and `B`, the value is the same `9128554507.850000000000000000000`. So they **should** be the same.

[image]

Then I saw the following in the documentation for the [CATS](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.5&docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=n1e21rr6al5m2nn19r1fat5qxwrt.htm&locale=en) function

> The CATS function removes leading and trailing blanks from numeric
> arguments after it formats the numeric value with the BESTw. format.

Then I thought it would be a good idea to transform the numeric variables to character variables.
I did it using this macro:

```
/*macro to convert all numeric to char*/
%macro vars(dsn, outp);
  %let list=;
  %let type=;
  %let dsid=%sysfunc(open(&dsn));
  %let cnt=%sysfunc(attrn(&dsid,nvars));
   %do i = 1 %to &cnt;
    %let list=&list %sysfunc(varname(&dsid,&i));
    %let type=&type %sysfunc(vartype(&dsid,&i));
   %end;
  %let rc=%sysfunc(close(&dsid));
  data &outp(drop=
    %do i = 1 %to &cnt;
     %let temp=%scan(&list,&i);
       _&temp
    %end;);
   set &dsn(rename=(
    %do i = 1 %to &cnt;
     %let temp=%scan(&list,&i);
       &temp=_&temp
    %end;));
    %do j = 1 %to &cnt;
     %let temp=%scan(&list,&j);
   /** Change C to N for numeric to character conversion  **/
     %if %scan(&type,&j) = N %then %do;
   /** Also change INPUT to PUT for numeric to character  **/
      &temp=PUT(_&temp,best.);
     %end;
     %else %do;
      &temp=_&temp;
     %end;
    %end;
  run;
%mend vars;
```

See that the `best.` format was used. Unfortunately I end up with the same value has before, a value for `A` of `9128554507.9` and `B` of `9128554507.8`. I don't know what is happening between the two data sets? The "real" value seems to be the same but when applying the `best.` format for both of then, SAS rounds the value of `A` to `.9` and the value of `B` to `.8`.

[image]

Is there any workaround ? I can't reproduce the error when trying to manually input the observation in a datalines statement. I don't want to round the values to a pre-defined decimal. Ideally, I would want to dynamically truncate the value to the `number of actual decimal - 1` (e.g. `3462829.374` becomes `3462829.37` and `18726347.39` becomes `18726347.3`) for both tables and then compare them.

Comment: I thought the goal was to compare them, so why are concatenating the two variables?  Why not just compare using the original two variables?

Comment: In the larger problem, I have ~15 columns in A and in B. I concat them and use md5() to compute a hash that I compare between the two tables. I only showed the variable (value) because this is the only one that cause problem.

Comment: I am curious why you are using macro functions for this instead of arrays in the data step. It would make the code easier to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what your larger problem is but to answer the question at the end just convert the number to a string using BEST32. format and remove the last character when the resulting string contains a decimal point.

```
data test;
  input number expect $32. ;
  string=put(number,best32.-l);
  if index(string,'.') then string=substrn(string,1,length(string)-1);
  format number best32. ;
cards;
3462829.374  3462829.37
18726347.39  18726347.3
12345 12345
.
;
```

Results:

```
Obs         number    expect        string

 1     3462829.374    3462829.37    3462829.37
 2     18726347.39    18726347.3    18726347.3
 3           12345    12345         12345
 4               .
```

Comment: Thank you. I finally went for the proc compare with a pre-defined criterion... Could you explain why is there a `-l` in your put statement ? `(string=put(number,best32.-l);)`

Comment: The hyphen el is for alignment. Normally numeric formats generated right aligned strings. By asking for the string to be left aligned from the beginning I eliminate the need to use a LEFT() or STRIP() function call to remove the leading spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Can you compute the fuzz and examine that ?

```
* retrieve a data from impala;
proc sql;
  create table b as select * from connection to impala (select * from a);

data a_b_fuzz;
  merge a b(rename=number=impala_number);
  by id;
  fuzz = number - impala_number;
run;
```